# Is it okay for a ViewModel's LiveData to include functions for its respective views to invoke?

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

Similar to iamjonfry's approach [here](https://iamjonfry.com/posts/lambdas-in-data-classes/)...

**Simple Example:**
Along with ui content (ie. `title`), my data class (`MyUIState`) has `onClicked` properties. When `MyFragment` with, say, a `RecyclerView` of buttons submits the `myViewsData` to a `ListAdapter`, the adapter sets the `OnClickListener` of each item to invoke the respective `onClicked` function in the data class (which originally came from the `ViewModel`)

```
// MyViewModel.kt - Note: It does not reference anything in Activity/Fragment/View layer

// Data Class representing State that will map to the View Layer
data class MyState(val myItems: List<Item>) {

    /* Other properties go here. Not necessary for sake of example */

    // Item will map to a button in the View Layer
    data class Item(
        val title: String,
        val onClicked: (() -> Unit)? // I want to know if this is okay to do
    )
}

//LiveData for Activity/Fragment/View to observe
val myStateLiveData: MutableLiveData<MyState> = MutableLiveData()

fun refreshState() {
    myStateLiveData.value = MyState(
        getRawData().map {
            MyState.Item(
                title = it.title,
                // Note the lambda being passed here...
                onClicked = { /* do stuff in here */ }
            )
        }
    )
}
```

**Main Question:** Is it a reasonable approach for a ViewModel's LiveData to include function types for its respective views to invoke (for example, to pass an `onClick` handler to a View)? If not, what's the proper standard?

Comment: Additionally, I've been told that there's risks of memory leaks with this method due to the passing of lambdas via data classes, but I've had trouble trying to confirm the validity of that argument. Is this true?

Comment: I'd say it's wrong - ViewModel layer should be unaware of views and their states, only relevant data should be whether observers are active or not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this will leak your UI components. Observers of LiveData are automatically disconnected when they go out of scope, so they are not leaked. But if the LiveData itself stores an indirect reference to a lambda that captures anything in an Activity or Fragment, that Activity or Fragment will be leaked. There's no mechanism to automatically drop the reference in your code. You theoretically could use WeakReferences, but that results in convoluted code, and you're violating MVVM anyway by passing UI references to a ViewModel.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Since my lambda is within my ViewModel, if the code in my lambda, does not capture anything in an Activity or Fragment (and simply just triggers business logic in my ViewModel), am I safe? My ViewModel never references anything within my View layer

Comment: That sounds safe. The names MyView and UIState are throwing me, since those names make it sound like they capture references to UI components.